# How to add domail alias in iRedMail open source edition?

Tags: linux, domain, alias, email-server

Looking at the vmail database of the iRedMail installation I see an alias_domain table which is currently empty.

Is it possible to add domain aliases with a MySQL query directly on the vmail.alias_domain table?

Comment: Iredmail gives you IredAdmin by which you can add domain and domain alias and it will get store in your mysql.

Answer (score 1):

To use my Canadian .ca site as an alias to my .com site I would use something like.

mysql -uroot -p
mysql> USE vmail;
mysql> INSERT INTO alias_domain (alias_domain, target_domain) values ('mysite.ca', 'mysite.com');

Comment: Did not work for me, any idea why? Mails are rejected with: ` Recipient address rejected: User unknown in virtual mailbox table.`

Comment: Field **active** needs to set to 1 as well. INSERT INTO alias_domain (alias_domain, target_domain, active) VALUES ('mysite.ca', 'mysite.com', 1);

Answer (score 0):

I created a script to do the dirty work.

Cut and paste below into a file add_domain.sh, then chmod 755 the file and run it with  *./add_domain.sh*  alias_domain target_existing_domain 
OR *./add_domain.sh list*    to list the existing domains.

---

```
#!/bin/bash
# 2014 Aug 16 James Forte, Magna Computer Corp

if [ "$1" == "list" ]
then
    mysql vmail -e 'select * from alias_domain'
    exit 0
fi

if [ $# -lt 2 ]
then
    echo usage "$0: alias_domain target_existing_domain"
    exit 1
fi

CREATED=`date  +%Y-%m-%d`

echo -e "\nScript assumes that .my.cnf has passwords in it\n"
echo "Adding alias domain $1 to existing domain $2"

mysql vmail -e "INSERT INTO alias_domain (alias_domain, target_domain, created, active) 
                VALUES ('$1','$2','$CREATED',1);"
exit 0
```